# Trying to create a Javascript Array that I can convert to Json

Tags: javascript, json

Hope someone can help me. I have the following function that returns this after JSON.stringify using javascript ;

`{"tablerows":[{"colone":"test","colthree:":"testf","row:0},{"colone":"testd","row":1}]}` however I am trying to get to something that give me another level for row so it would be like
row0
row0.colone:test
row0.colthree:testf 
row1 
row1.colone: testd
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
             var row = table.rows[i];
             var currentrowcellcount = $('td', row).length;

```
          if (currentrowcellcount == 4) {
          var colone = row.cells[0].childNodes[0].childNodes  [0].innerHTML;

          var coltwo = row.cells[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML;

          var colthree = row.cells[2].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
                tablerow = {
                    'colone': colone,
                    'coltwo': coltwo,
                    'colthree': colthree
                }
                container.tablerows.push(tablerow);
                container.tablerows[i].row = i;
            }
            else if (currentrowcellcount == 2) {
                var fieldnameone = row.cells[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML;

            }
        }
        $('#SuccessUpdate').fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
        alert(JSON.stringify(container));
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how do I get a json result that looks like this?

Comment: {row0 row0.colone:test row0:colthree:testf} {row1 row1.colone:testd}

Answer (score 0):

In this question is missing the quotation. I got take the json values:

```
var test = {"tablerows":[{"colone":"test","colthree:":"testf","row":0},{"colone":"testd","row":1}]};

console.log(test.tablerows[0].colone); 
console.log(test.tablerows[1].row);
```

See the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5b4608b9/

Comment: How do I add my function into this forum so you can see it?